# Why do you have to search for TXIDs in little-endian?

Tags: transaction-id, bitcoin-cli

I understand that when you double-sha256 some transaction data, it will give you the TXID for that transaction. This can then be used in future transaction data when you want to reference an existing transaction.

However, if you want to *search* for a TXID using bitcoin-cli or a blockexplorer, you have to convert this TXID to little-endian.

```
TXID (original):  B0570984EA35E417A20327D72414CDA0EB8200418772FA3E1A28D76EF4977CF2
TXID (searching): F27C97F46ED7281A3EFA7287410082EBA0CD1424D72703A217E435EA840957B0
```

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Because Bitcoin in general uses little-endian while most hashing libraries use big-endian.

For more details and links see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/why-does-the-bitcoin-protocol-use-the-little-endian-notation).

Comment: If bitcoin uses little-endian, why not use little-endian TXIDs in the transaction data? I don't understand the purpose of converting to little-endian for the user's side of things only.