# What does the little-endian notation improve for Bitcoin?

Tags: protocol, endianness

In another [thread](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/why-does-the-bitcoin-protocol-use-the-little-endian-notation) I read that the little-endian notation speeds things(?) up. Has someone info on what exactly it improves for Bitcoin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost all CPUs these days work natively in little-endian. To operate on big-endian numbers, additional byteswap instructions are needed.

For most things, I think this effect is negligible. Network protocols need a convention to represent things, and Bitcoin's creator picked one. The actual choice barely matters.